# Plotting RGB matrix in numpy & matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, rgb

I'm trying to plot a numpy array with shape [height x width x 3] containing RGB values. As a simple example suppose you have the Belgian flag:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flag = np.empty((1,3,3))
flag[0,0,:] = (0,0,0)
flag[0,1,:] = (254,240,71)
flag[0,2,:] = (255,55,14)
plt.imshow(flag)
plt.show()
```

This results in the following output: 
[image]

Can anyone tell me why it is not plotting the right RGB values? Did I make a mistake in the dimensionality? Probably an easy answer to this, but can't seem to find it .. Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: To use integer values in `imshow`, convert your array to unsigned integer via `plt.imshow(flag.astype(np.uint8))`.

Answer (score 2):

The default data type for the array created by `numpy.empty` is floating point, and `imshow` treats floating point values differently than integer values. (`imshow` expects floating point values to be in the range 0.0 to 1.0.)

Change this

```
flag = np.empty((1,3,3))
```

to

```
flag = np.empty((1,3,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

---

The reason you got those particular colors when `flag` is floating point is that `imshow` apparently converted your array to integer without checking that the input values were in the range 0.0 to 1.0.  Here's what happens in that case:

```
In [25]: flag
Out[25]: 
array([[[   0.,    0.,    0.],
        [ 254.,  240.,   71.],
        [ 255.,   55.,   14.]]])

In [26]: img = (flag*255).astype(np.uint8)

In [27]: img
Out[27]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  2,  16, 185],
        [  1, 201, 242]]], dtype=uint8)
```

If you then run `imshow(img)`, you get the black, blue and cyan plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the float values between 0 ~ 1.
So change the code like this,

```
flag[0,0,:] = (0,0,0)
flag[0,1,:] = (254/255,240/255,71/255)
flag[0,2,:] = (255/255,55/255,14/255)
```